# Warning: undefined callback function terminate/3 (behaviour 'gen_statem')**

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

How serious is this warning? Can I use this module with this warning? What the side-effects of this warning.

> Warning: undefined callback function terminate/3 (behaviour
> 'gen_statem')**

```
Erlang/OTP: 19.0.7

 
git clone https://github.com/inaka/apns4erl.git
cd apns4erl/
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rebar3/rebar3 && chmod +x rebar3
./rebar3 compile
===> Fetching coveralls v2.2.0
===> Fetching jsx v2.10.0
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling jsx
===> Compiling coveralls
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Fetching base64url v1.0.1
===> Fetching gun v1.3.3
===> Fetching jsx v3.0.0
===> Fetching cowlib v2.7.3
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling cowlib
===> Compiling base64url
===> Compiling gun
===> Compiling jsx
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling apns
**src/apns_connection.erl:22: Warning: undefined callback function terminate/3 (behaviour 'gen_statem')**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Erlang/OTP 19.3 and later, as a result of [this change](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/913d0b52df1e029fb1728b44ba7da318f3dc49dd), the `terminate/3` callback is optional for gen_statem.  As stated in [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#Module:terminate-3):

> This callback is optional, so callback modules need not export it. The gen_statem module provides a default implementation without cleanup.

---

So let's figure out what the consequences are of not including this function in earlier versions.  According to the documentation, the `terminate` function would be called in three different cases:

- another callback function has returned a stop tuple `{stop,Reason}` in `Actions`
- the gen_statem is part of a supervision tree and is ordered by its supervisor to terminate (only if the gen_statem has been set to trap exit signals, and the shutdown strategy is not `brutal_kill`)
- the process receives an `'EXIT'` message from its parent

It's certainly imaginable that none of those situations would arise for a particular gen_statem, and thus the lack of a `terminate` function would have no negative consequences.  In the worst case, the `terminate` function would be called when the process was already about to exit, thus terminating the process with a different exit reason than the original one, hiding the cause of the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

> How serious is this warning?

A function that is supposed to be defined is not there.

> Can I use this module with this warning?

Supervisors use the terminate() function to shut down a child process when necessary.  If the child process never needs shutting down, then you are good.

You could add a do nothing terminate function to the source code:

```
terminate(_Reason, _State, _Data) -> ok.
```

But, a better option might be to report the error to the github repository and hopefully they will make a quick fix to the code.

Or, you could try upgrading your erlang version.  In newer erlang versions, the terminate() function is automatically defined for you.

> What the side-effects of this warning.

Your program crashes at some point.